# Downloading part of a song and then playing it

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, audio, amazon-s3

I am using amazon s3 bucket technology and I  have a program that downloads bytes from parts of a `.wav` file and, for instance, I would call a method like

```
getPartOfASongFile(String filename, long byteToStartAt, long byteToEndAt)` and then play it using a Clip.
```

The program works as long as `byteToStartAt==0`. Anything above 0 and I get a

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file`.
```

My question is: How do I play this file if I want to get the byteToStartAt to be greater than zero?

This is basically the current program:

```
getPartOfASongFile(String filename,long byteToStartAt,long byteToEndAt){
    File tempFile= null;
    try {
        tempFile = File.createTempFile(filename, ".wav");
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    FileOutputStream out=null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    GetObjectRequest rangeObjectRequest=new GetObjectRequest("myBucketName",filename);
    rangeObjectRequest.setRange(byteToStartAt, byteToEndAt);
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(awsClient.getObject(rangeObjectRequest).getObjectContent(), out);
    } catch (AmazonClientException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream=null;
    audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(tempFile);
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();

    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
}
```

Comment: Post your program, otherwise it is really hard to speculate what is going on.

Comment: @dambros just edited it

Comment: if this is a file (and I dont know how your dowloading works) it must have some header info in the beginning so skipping that causes the error - you can load the file and play from certain part - otherwise skipping the first bytes of an mp3 or wav will not work